# how to run hello-exe in the Android emulator

Tags: android-ndk

I compiled the hello-exe sample, which is contained in the Android ndk. The problem is that I don't know how to run it on the emulator (I'm using the Windows emulator).

Any ideas?

Also, is there a way to telnet into the emulator, and run programs, like in a regular Linux terminal?

thanks,
Joan

Answer (score 0):

You can get a shell on the emulator using:

adb shell

Do you mean the hello-jni sample from the NDK? I'm not familiar with a hello-exe. But the answer is that you need to build the Java code next (using Eclipse or Ant) and run it from there. See the NDK instructions again; it's all there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the hello-jni application, the easiest way is to use Eclipse (see Android SDK docs for setup) and the emulator.

If you're running a standalone executable, you can use 'adb shell' to shell into the device. The executable will need placed somewhere that you can set execute (via chmod) permissions such as /data/local